# How to find I2C address of an STM32L031K6

Tags: microcontroller, i2c

I'm trying to use an STM32 L031k6 microcontroller in an I2C-bus, but I can't find its address. I have read the data sheet for the device provided by STM, but couldn't find anything there either. Do you have any tips for how I can find its address?

Comment: If the STM32 has firmware running, and if that firmware configures and operates it as an I2C *slave* device, then it's I2C slave address is entirely dependent on that firmware. It could be any 7-bit value. Do you know for certain that your STM32 does actually have any I2C slave mode firmware running in it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the MCU as a slave, you define the address, there is no default and it is not even listening any address unless you configure it as a slave and tell which address it has.

If you are using the MCU as a master only, it will also not have a slave address as it does not need one.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0377-ultralowpower-stm32l0x1-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), two slave addresses may be porogrammed to any 7 or 10-bit value in OAR1 (OAR2 is 7-bit only) as shown in the images below. This allows the MCU to be two different slave devices.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The I2C registers will be dependent on the software running on the device.There are tools available online to do I2C port scans to scan all addresses so if you don't know the software you could use one of those to find the address. Make sure the port is a slave mode port.